# Merge same data with Key

Tags: javascript, merge, key

This is the data I have

```
 {
  "entity": "student",
  "records": [
    {
      "associatedStudentId": 111,
      "data": {
         "info":{
           "position": 1,
           "id": 111
         },
         "entity":{
            "id": 222
         }
      }
    },
    {
      "associatedStudentId": 222,
      "data": {
         "info":{
           "position": 2,
           "id": 222
         },
         "entity":{
            "id": 222
         }
      }
    }
  ],
  "personalInfo": {
      "111":{
        "Father_Name": "Amar"
      },
      "222":{
        "Father_Name": "Akbar"
      }
  }
}
```

This is the result I get

```
[{
"key": 111,
"student_Info": {
  
},
"personal_Info":{

} }]
```

But I need to get this result

```
[ {
"key": 111,
"student_Info": [
  
],
"personal_Info":{

} }]
```

This is what I tried:

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./student_data.json');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);

    let tempStudents=[]
    let tempInfo=[]
    let students = jmespath.search(data,"records[*].{key: associatedStudentId, student_Info:data}")
    students.forEach((element, value) => {
        tempStudents.push(element)
    });
    let info = jmespath.search(data,"values(personal_Info)[*].{key: entity.id, value: @}")
    info.forEach((element, value) => {
        tempInfo.push(element)
    });

    student_data=tempInfo.concat(tempStudents)
    
    const res = Object.values(student_data.reduce((acc,{name,...rest}) => {
      acc[name]??={name}
      acc[name] = {...acc[name],...rest}
      return acc
    },{}))
    
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: whats the structure of data. why no associatedStudentId for second record

Comment: @cmgchess- oops sorry typo error- Added now